# Android Real Device vs Emulator for Google SignIn Api's

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

Google Sign in API works on Emulator but not works on Real Device when debuging.

Emulator is succesfully loggin in with Google SignIn API. But same code doesn't work on my Xperia Z3 when I try debugging.

Real Device also connected via USB.

Here Google SignIn API's results.

Emulator:

```
GoogleSignInResult result
result = {GoogleSignInResult@831568010912} 
hv = {Status@831562736800} "Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}"
```

Real Device:

```
GoogleSignInResult result
result = {GoogleSignInResult@5615} 
hv = {Status@5639} "Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}"
```